# 502 Whoops, Bad Gateway GitLab is taking too much time to respond

Tags: ruby, http, nginx, gitlab

I am new to gitlab and I am trying to rerun and an old git server which has been down for few weeks. It was working a month back, but suddenly it stopped working. I have also tried to upgrade the GitLab. But still error is same.

Output for # gitlab-ctl tail is as follows

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2019-06-26_08:56:26.40033 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 10:56:26.366423831 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2422 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.033868
2019-06-26_08:56:26.45517 2019/06/26 10:56:26 Send static file "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/favicon.ico" ("") for GET "/favicon.ico"
2019-06-26_08:56:26.47561 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 10:56:26.454851912 +0200 CEST] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "http://10.5.11.118/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.020684
2019-06-26_09:17:01.51633 2019/06/26 11:17:01 error: GET "/": badgateway: failed after 0.000s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused
2019-06-26_09:17:01.51647 2019/06/26 11:17:01 ErrorPage: serving predefined error page: 502
2019-06-26_09:17:01.51648 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 11:17:01.515397035 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2422 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.000799
2019-06-26_09:24:39.79408 2019/06/26 11:24:39 Starting gitlab-workhorse v0.8.5-20161031.150348
2019-06-26_09:40:51.86440 2019/06/26 11:40:51 error: GET "/": badgateway: failed after 0.000s: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused
2019-06-26_09:40:51.86446 2019/06/26 11:40:51 ErrorPage: serving predefined error page: 502
2019-06-26_09:40:51.86459 10.5.11.118 @ - - [2019-06-26 11:40:51.862764251 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2422 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36" 0.001769

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/current <==
2019-06-26_09:48:30.83101 master failed to start, check stderr log for details
2019-06-26_09:48:31.83785 failed to start a new unicorn master
2019-06-26_09:48:31.85436 starting new unicorn master

==> /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log <==
I, [2019-06-26T11:48:32.609507 #10462]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

and I am also getting following in loop in /var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:115:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:114:in `each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru:19:in `require'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru:19:in `block in <main>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru:1:in `new'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `eval'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn.rb:56:in `block in builder'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:752:in `build_app!'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:129:in `start'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn:22:in `load'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn:22:in `<top (required)>
```

'

I really do not know how to solve this issue. Please can someone help me.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Did you check whats in `/var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log`?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this in loop

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:115:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:114:in `each'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/1_settings.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'

Comment: Looks like a problem in `initializers/1_settings.rb` on line 115. Whats in there? Maybe you dont set some env variable when you start a server